# Is Ubuntu/Unity More CPU or GPU Intensive?

Tags: 11.10, performance

The answer is really important. I want to know if it's more cpu or gpu intensive I'm choosing between sandy bridge and llano.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I doubt you'll notice much difference in Unity performance with either architecture. I would base your choice on what you want to do application-wise rather than your desktop environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2D is more CPU intensive, 3D is more GPU intensive.